# Use a Select Statement within a wildcard where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, query-optimization

Working in MS SQL 2005 and I want to use a select statement within a wildcard where clause like so:

```
SELECT text
FROM table_1
WHERE ID LIKE '%SELECT ID FROM table_2%'
```

I'm looking for product ids within a large body of text that is held in a DB.  The SELECT statement in the wildcard clause will return 50+ rows.  The statement above is obviously not the way to go.  Any suggestions?

Comment: HAve you tried using an IN clause instead of a LIKE?

Comment: I tried the IN clause which didn't work.  Then again, I'm not be writing the statement correctly.  The SELECT statement in the wildcard clause is going to return 50+ results which might change everyone's answer a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a join and construct the like string based on table_2.

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 t1
INNER JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.ID LIKE '%' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, t2.ID) + '%'
```